# Decomposing the tensor product $10⊗24$ in term of tensors under SU(5) group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, tensor-decomposition

Suppose that the rank two tensor $C_{ij}=10$ is an antisymmetric representation of SU(5) group and $24$ is the adjoint representation which written as rank two tensor $D_{kl}=24$

I understand that the tensor product of $10⊗24=C_{ij}⊗D_{kl}$ can be decomposed under SU(5) group as a sum
$$10⊗24=10⊕15⊕40⊕175$$

but I don't know how to write the sum $10⊕15⊕40⊕175$ in term of tensors $C_{ij}⊗D_{kl}$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)